# Filter out Previous Weeks that have not yet happened yet in Current Year

Tags: date, tableau-api

I have this visualization (gray = 2017, green = 2018): 
[image]
I would like to remove the weeks from 2017 that haven't happened in 2018. In other words, remove the weeks in the red rectangle.

I have access to Tableau server so ideally the solution would be as a calculated field with no parameters, sets and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a calculated field with below formula and filter on True.(In my example I am using 2015 as the partial year, but you might want to use YEAR(TODAY()). Basically, it checks whether the week number is lower or equal to the maximum week number encountered in 2015. Please note that you need to use a table scoped LOD expression as you are mixing aggregate and non aggregate calculations.

```
DATEPART('week',[Order Date]) <= {
MAX(
IF YEAR([Order Date]) = 2015 
    THEN DATEPART('week',[Order Date]) 
END)
}
```

[image]
[image]